# Question about combinatorial analysis

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:** A Professor of Combinatorics has 3 classes, which do not share students in common. He decided to reward his students as follows: One student will be drawn from each class. Then, those drawn with an average greater than 9 will be awarded. (That is, if the draw did not have a score greater than 9, the class will not have any winners.)  Knowing that class A has 25 students, class B has 30 and class C, 35. How many possibilities are there of awards?

**What I did:** I reasoned as follows. There is a possibility that they have a score above nine, so: $25 \cdot 30 \cdot 35$. Or there is the possibility that only two have a score above nine: $25 \cdot 30$ or $30 \cdot 35$ or $25 \cdot 35$. Or there is still the possibility that only one of the students drawn has a score above nine. In the end I added up all these possibilities. But why is it wrong?

Comment: This doesn't seem solvable with just this information. Is there any info missing, such as the distribution of grades for each class?

Comment: Also, it's impossible to tell you where you went wrong without knowing ALL of your working. What you wrote sounds like a very brief summary. Not enough info

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your approach sounds right to me, but did you include the possibility of no awards?

Comment: With simple 'adjustment', you should see that the result is (also) $26.31.36$